# Cannot instantiate java.util.List as a JavaBeans component

Tags: java, netbeans, javabeans

I'm trying to add java.util.List as a Bean in a Java Application on Netbeans, but when I select "Choose Bean" and input java.util.List, the error below is shown on the screen:

> Cannot instantiate java.util.List as a JavaBeans component
>   A usual cause of this error is that the class is abstract or does not have a public constructor with no parameters

My class CadastroFuncionario already has a public constructor with no params.

Comment: Which is correct-a List isn't an implementation. I don't see what the issue is--is there a typing issue? *Your* class isn't relevant here.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, no? List is an interface

Comment: I'm watching a CRUD tutorial and the guy could perform this action, I'm not sure why I can't. @DaveNewton There is not a typing issue.

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface. Try using one of its implementations, e.g. `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Hi @kidney I have just tried using ArrayList and it worked! I was going to post here right now, but you were faster :p

Comment: @Pedro: Good for you;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of the day, java.util.List cannot be instantiated because it is an interface. I used java.util.ArrayList instead and it worked.

Comment: So, a typing issue.

Comment: misconception issue i would rather say :p Thanks for helping, @DaveNewton